# How to keep a table that contains select query results

Tags: c#

Hi
I have 2 select queries that are returned to two seperate tables.
While i am processing one of them inside a function i need the other query result to be kept inside a global parameter.
How do i save the query result so it wont be overwritten when the function works?
Thanks

Comment: "returned to tables"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Could you post some example code of what you have at the moment?

Comment: I guess your problem is that you **have** a global parameter. But you might show some code (simplified if too long) to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you need to store it in a variable outside of the scope of the 'Execute Query' method?

To do that declare a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9186hy08%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) variable (or whatever you're using to store the result) outside of the method and simply set it to the query result when you execute the query. Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     private DataTable _mySavedQueryResult = null;

     private void ExecuteMyQuery()
     {
          // Execute the query
         _mySavedQueryResult = ... // result of copy of the result query 
    }
}
```

You can then use _mySavedQueryResult to access the result of the query after you have exited `ExecuteMyQuery`.